# Какая разница между объявлениями глобальных переменных с var и без?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть код:

```
// вне всяких блоков и функций
var a1 = 'Something';
a2 = 'Something';
```

1) В чём будет разница между переменные `a1` и `a2`?
2) Является ли вообще `a2` переменной?
3) Где-нибудь можно использовать второй вариант?

Comment: [Вот объяснение](http://learn.javascript.ru/variables#%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-var) данной темы из хорошего учебника по JS. Рекоммендую ознакомиться. *P.S. Оставил бы комментарий, да пока не могу.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В чём будет разница между переменные a1 и a2?

В режиме strict вариант без var будет сломан:

```js
'use strict';

var a1 = 'Something';
a2 = 'Something'; // Uncaught ReferenceError: a2 is not defined
```

> Является ли вообще a2 переменной?

Разумеется, а чем же ещё?

> Где-нибудь можно использовать второй вариант?

Это дело каждого, но смысла в этом немного.
Гораздо лучше явно обозначать глобальный объект(ака `window.a2 = 42;`).
Ещё лучше - не засорять глобальный scope совсем.

Answer (score 4):

1) В старом стандарте можно было работать и без `var`, просто присвоив значение.
С `"use strict"` уже нельзя.
2) Да, является:

> Присвоение значения необъявленной переменной подразумевает, что она
>   будет создана как глобальная переменная (переменная становится
>   свойством глобального объекта) после выполнения присваивания значения.

Т. е. до присвоения её нет и будет ошибка при обращении до присвоения; а вот с `var` переменная инициализируется до выполнения текущего блока.
3) Можно. Но нужны ли описанные выше проблемы?

Подробнее, много полезного: [javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/variables), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 3):

Это скорее не ответ, а комментарий к ответу выше. (Комментарии мне пока не доступны, пардон)

1.Если обратиться к объявленной переменной до присваивания ей значения, на выходе получите **undefined**, в случае с необъявленной - **ReferenceError**.
Это происходит, потому что переменная **а1** уже объявлена и существует, переменная **а2** соответсвенно не объявлена и не существует.

```js
console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);

var a1 = 'Something';
a2 = 'Something';
```

2. Является.
3. Можно, но смысла в этом никакого.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная объявленная без var (или let или const) попадает в глобальный объект:

```js
(function(){
  var a = 1;
  b = 2;
})();

console.log(b);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: А Вы проверяли свой сниппет? :) Он во втором случае выдает `Uncaught ReferenceError`.

Comment: @Yaant вы так говорите, как будто это что то плохое

Comment: Ну, немного плохо, что это не совсем согласуется с комментариями в коде :)

Comment: @Yaant пофикшено

Comment: Но в вопросе написано же "вне всяких блоков и функций"

Comment: Докапываться, так докапываться. :) Всё равно из ответа непонятно, если _"переменная объявленная без var попадает в глобальный объект"_, то почему выдается ошибка? :)

Comment: Необъявленные переменные не существуют до тех пор, пока к ним не выполнено присваивание. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: @Yaant потому что ошибка выпадает на переменную `a`, которая объявлена с  `var`. А вообще, мне кажется, в ответе нет ответов на вопросы ТС)

Comment: На самом деле, `var` в глобальном контексте тоже объявляет переменную как свойство глобального объекта `window`. Попробуйте: `var a1 = 42; alert(window.a1);`